# Open a geoprocessing tool / custom script tool window as a result of python code compilation

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool, user-interface

I am trying to create a custom system for converting general geodata to S-57 standard.

This will require more than one custom tool/script, but I'd like to make the experience as user-friendly as possible.

ModelBuilder won't do, because the user inputs I wish to get depend on the data itself, and I'm trying to avoid asking for dozens of inputs and then not using most of them.

---

Therefore, I'm looking for a method for ArcPy (or Python in general) to open a custom tool window mid-script or after a previous custom tool has finished running - as if the user went to the toolbox and double clicked the tool. Maybe even with some pre-loaded parameters out of the previous tool.

I know how to run custom tools within another custom tool, but not how to request user input to the inner tool via familiar interface.

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used them in earnest, but to get the interactivity you seek, I think what you may need to look at is authoring a task.

From [What is a task?](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/tasks/whatistask.htm):

> A task is a set of preconfigured steps that guide you and others
> through a workflow or business process. A task can be used to
> implement a best-practice workflow, improve the efficiency of a
> workflow, or create a series of interactive tutorial steps.

You can certainly use geoprocessing tools for task steps, and I assume that those geoprocessing tools can include Python script tools.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll definitely check that one out. There so are many ArcGIS Pro functionalities that I already gave up on long ago when I couldn’t see their usability.

Comment: Hey, thanks again for your reply. I checked that out, but it's more of an automated process generator that heavily relays on the active view. It's impossible to pass parameters between steps of that process, as they have to be in the active view from the beginning of the entire process. It may be possible if I create some argument table and conduct edits in each step, but creating a condition process that way feels quite wrong... and again, I need things created by tools to pass to other tools, not only things that are prepared in advanced in the active view.